# Can't initialize use of double (fp64) in OpenCL programs

Tags: floating-point, double, opencl

when I use the following line in my OpenCL programs

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

I get the following OpenCL error:

```
cl::Error: -46, (std::exception.what() returns "clCreateKernel")
```

Does anyone know why?
What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I have the following system:

```
[INFO] Name: GeForce GTX 470
[INFO] Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[INFO] Profile: FULL_PROFILE
[INFO] Version: OpenCL 1.0 CUDA
[INFO] Driver: 260.19.06
```

Cheers,

Comment: What is the build log? You should get it and print it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the OpenCL 1.0 driver for GeForce GTX 470 you're using doesn't support fp64.

Try the new OpenCL 1.1 driver available [here.](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/opencl.html)

Comment: Are you sure it's about drivers? Anyway, Given I use Ubuntu to develop/run OpenCL I'll better wait 11.04 to come out with next drivers...It's not urgent to switch to double precision. thanks again!

Comment: The OpenCL 1.0 drivers support double precision just fine. Check the kernel build log.

Comment: Ah, sorry for giving the wrong suggestion... my apologies. Could you un-check my answer, @Emanuele?

Comment: I have a similar problem, with `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable ` clCreateKernel returns CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME error. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using C stringification macro by any chance?

If so, you need to change your code to look like this:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable \n
```

This is because stringification process takes all whitespace and converts it into one space. However, C-preprocessor require "newline" to delimit the next line.

Comment: I'm not using that, because I'm reading the whole text file into a std::string ... anyway will give a shot!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I added spaces and newlines and it didn't solve it. It build but clCreateKernel returns CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME